# Stop Xcode automatically generating Swift interfaces for Objective-C headers

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Is it possible to stop Xcode (8) from automatically generating a Swift interface when showing an Objective-C header? For example by setting a user defaults value.

In theory it’s a really nice feature of Xcode. Unfortunately it doesn’t work reliably. For me it even seem to fail most of the time. As I haven’t been able to discern why it happens, I’d like to opt out of it, until the bugs Xcode/SourceKit have been resolved.

Comment: You're talking about what happens when you ⌘-click on a class name?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes indeed. As well as when you open a header, or navigate to a symbol in a header, using “Open Quickly…”.

Comment: If nothing else I'd like to be able to see the original Objective-C, just for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour should be dependent on your project settings. If you're in a Swift project it will want to show you Swift interfaces. Also if there is an Objective-C interface that Xcode generate Swift from then using Cmd+Alt+Enter you should be able to look at the Objective-C header "Counterpart" of the Swift code there for comparison.