# How do I prevent Xcode 10 from generating Swift interfaces in a c++ project?

Tags: c++, swift, xcode

I have a C++ project in [Xcode 10.3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_3_release_notes) that has started generating Swift interfaces, which makes code navigation difficult.

I am not sure what caused this to happen and how do I stop this?

Build settings appear to all be C++.

All my source files are marked as either C or C++ headers or C++ source.

Comment: Have you had a peek at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502323/stop-xcode-automatically-generating-swift-interfaces-for-objective-c-headers

Comment: @Adrian Yes — I didn't see any solutions there. AFAIK, I haven't done anything to indicate to Xcode that I have a swift project.

Comment: I haven't had to monkey with that before, but I suspect the solution lives somewhere in the build settings. You might have to poke around and change some stuff most folks never fiddle around with.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13834705/11887253 I still see the interface files, but Xcode once again recognizes headers as C++